# Concat two strings in powershell and supply as one parameter

Tags: string, powershell, concatenation

I am trying to concatinate two strings into a variable and then supple the new variable as a parameter in a command

```
$firstName = Read-Host -Prompt 'enter user first name'
$lastName = Read-Host -Prompt 'enter user last name'
$userAblevetsEmail = '' + $firstName + '.' + $lastName + '@company.com'
New-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $userAblevetsEmail  -DisplayName $firstName + " " + $lastName -FirstName $firstName
```

I get the following error:

> "New-MsolUser : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts
>   argument '+'."

Comment: use the string formatter `$userAblevetsEmail = "{0}.{1}@company.com" -f $firstName, $lastName`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code `New-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $userAblevetsEmail  -DisplayName $firstName + " " + $lastName -FirstName $firstName` is slightly off.

The info following `-DisplayName` cannot have spaces without being contained inside of something.

Here is an example fix:

`New-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $userAblevetsEmail  -DisplayName "$firstName $lastName" -FirstName $firstName`

You can simply use the variables directly inside quotation marks.

Comment: Yet another one: put them inside parentheses  `-DisplayName ($firstName + " " + $lastName)`